# How to get parent component to re render after a fetch call in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, backend

I Want the parent component to re-render as this fetch request completes. With the current code it seems to be rendering before fetch completes no matter what. I'm guessing this is due to asynchronous nature of fetch? Is there a way this can be somehow achieved inside a .then() ? trying to call "this.props.rerenderParentCallback()" inside a .then() is giving me errors.

```
submit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const myInit1 = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                'Vary': 'Origin'.replace,
                'Accept': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                "username": this.state.username,
                "password": this.state.password,
                "email": this.state.email
            })
        };
        console.log(myInit1.body);
        let authurl = 'http://localhost:8080/authenticate';
        if(!!localStorage.getItem("token"))
        localStorage.removeItem("token");
        try {
            fetch(authurl, myInit1)
                .then((response) => {
                    return response.json();
                })
                .then(function (myJson) {
                    console.log(myJson.token);
                    localStorage.setItem("token", myJson.token);
                    console.log("isAuth " + !!localStorage.getItem("token"));    
                }).then();
                
        } catch (e) {

        }finally{
            this.props.rerenderParentCallback();
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Currently the only operation happening in response to the AJAX operation is setting a value in local storage.  React doesn't monitor local storage for changes.  It *does* however monitor React state for changes.  Is there any state in your component?  If not, it sounds like there should be.  When you update state the component will re-render.

Comment: rerenderParentCallback(); is actually a parent function that force renders the parent component. The only problem is it doesnt get called after completion of fetch somehow(asynchronous nature??)

Answer (score 1):

You're calling the function *immediately*, before the AJAX operation completes:

```
this.props.rerenderParentCallback();
```

AJAX is asynchronous.  Anything you want to happen in response to an asynchronous operation would be in the `.then()` appended to the operation (or following an `await`, or in a passed-in callback, depending on how the asynchronous operation is structured).

In this case you'd also need to account for the fact that `this` means something different in that callback.  For that, simply assign the function reference to a variable and reference that variable.  Something like this:

```
const callback = this.props.rerenderParentCallback;

// then, in your .then() callback:
.then(function (myJson) {
    console.log(myJson.token);
    localStorage.setItem("token", myJson.token);
    console.log("isAuth " + !!localStorage.getItem("token"));
    callback(); // <--- invoke the function
})
```

(You can also get rid of the try/catch/finally structure entirely and just invoke the `fetch` operation.  If the `fetch` might fail, append a `.catch()` to the `.then()` chain and handle it there.)

Answer (score 0):

Why would the parent component need to re-render? You're not changing any of its state, thus not giving it a reason to re-render. Instead you can do something like this:

```js
function MyComponent() {
    const [someState, setSomeState] = React.useState(defaultValue);

    console.log('Rendering with state', someState);

    // whatever asynchronous operation you want
    setTimeout(() => setSomeState(newValue), 1e3);

    return <p>{new Date()}</p>;
}
```

You'll first see it render once with `defaultValue`, then after a second with `newValue`. With the `useState` hook, whenever you change the state from somewhere, it'll tell React "this component's state updated, please re-render it".

It's a bit rare in your case that you perform an operation and do something with the result that requires the component to re-render, even though the component doesn't seem to actually use the result? *or at least not directly.*

For your component, `defaultValue` could be read from `localStorage`. And whenever you call `setSomeState`, you can also directly save the new value to `localStorage`. Your component will be able to directly use the value without having to read `localStorage` every render.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have access to this inside then. If you use arrow methods as below, you should be able to access it.

```
submit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const myInit1 = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Vary': 'Origin'.replace,
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            "username": this.state.username,
            "password": this.state.password,
            "email": this.state.email
        })
    };
    console.log(myInit1.body);
    let authurl = 'http://localhost:8080/authenticate';
    if(!!localStorage.getItem("token"))
    localStorage.removeItem("token");
    try {
        fetch(authurl, myInit1)
            .then((response) => {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then((myJson)=> {
                console.log(myJson.token);
                localStorage.setItem("token", myJson.token);
                console.log("isAuth " + !!localStorage.getItem("token"));    
            }).then();
            
    } catch (e) {

    }finally{
        this.props.rerenderParentCallback();
    }
    
}
```

Here is another way of doing this using async await.

```
submit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const myInit1 = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'Vary': 'Origin'.replace,
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            "username": this.state.username,
            "password": this.state.password,
            "email": this.state.email
        })
    };
    console.log(myInit1.body);
    let authurl = 'http://localhost:8080/authenticate';
    if(!!localStorage.getItem("token"))
    localStorage.removeItem("token");
    try {
       const response = await fetch(authurl, myInit1);
       const myJson = await response.json();

       console.log(myJson.token);
       localStorage.setItem("token", myJson.token);
       console.log("isAuth " + !!localStorage.getItem("token"));    
       /*
       * you may write it here
       * this.props.rerenderParentCallback();
       */     
    } catch (e) {

    }finally{
        this.props.rerenderParentCallback();
    }
    
}
```